# Bundling less and css files together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, less, bundling-and-minification

I feel like bundling should be used to group a bunch of files which you use together into one single delivery to the browser. This would mean for example for my root style I would like to do something like the following:

```
var bundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/style").Include(
    "~/Content/mystyle.less",
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css");
bundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
bundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(bundle);
```

But this doesn't seem to work very well with the [custom transform technique for bundling less files](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2012/06/04/web-optimization-in-visual-studio-2012-rc/) as it looks like it pre-bundles all of the files into a single css file before passing it to the LessTransform. From what i can tell this method only works if you bundle all of your less files together.

Is there a way to get bundles to allow both less and css files in the same bundle?

Comment: I think the 'StyleBundle' already has a CssMinify transformer registered when you instantiate it. In the code you posted it means that it will try to minify the Less file before the less transformer. Either use the plain 'Bundle' type or clear the Transforms list before adding the less transformer.

Comment: @rmac this sounds exactly like whats occurring. ill give that a go.

Comment: My apologies, I had initially considered this. But I *thought* I had checked `StyleBundle` / `Bundle` within the link you gave and ruled it out. But on reviewing the blog, I see I was mistaken. I suspect this to be the case too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit more of a look into this and tried using Bundle instead of StyleBundle but still had issues. I think the issue is specifically to do with the bootstrap.css file having some syntax which less doesn't like.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are right, the transformer concatenates all the CSS/LESS contents before passing it along to the converter. That said, the converter should not be choking the presence of both LESS and CSS, as you can always include standard CSS within a LESS stylesheet.

The issue seems to be that you are using a `StyleBundle` object that already has a transformer associated. Try using a generic `Bundle` as I do in my config, like this:

```
var customStyles = new Bundle("~/bundle/style/css")
                       .Include("~/Content/normalize.css","~/Content/*.less");
bootstrapStyles.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
bootstrapStyles.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(customStyles);
```

As for your own answer below, the issue with the bootstrap.css file is not that the LESS transformer doesn't like it, but probably a path issue for @imports, make sure your LESS transformer uses something to ensure it resolves the proper paths to the any dependency stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

I believe all CSS is valid LESS (but not all LESS is valid CSS)

So having the `LessTransform` applied to your bootstrap css files shouldn't make any difference.

It will still bundle all files into one css file to deliver to the browser.

There might only be a *performance* problem during **design-time**.

The correct output will still be produced and caching will prevent any **run-time** performance issues.

Comment: This was my first thought too (as less *is* a superset of css), however something happens first before it even gets to the less transform to 'break' the bundle when you have both less and css files included (but interestingly not when you have only less).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit of an old post, but I've noticed something weird that may be of use to someone...

I've found that `Bundle` object doesn't like hyphens in the name of the css file when less files are also included. i.e.:

```
var frontendStyles = new Bundle("~/bundles/frontend.main.css")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/less", "*.less")
            .Include(
                "~/Content/ladda.css",
                "~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css",
                "~/Content/jquery-ui.1.9.2.custom.css"
            );
```

Doesn't work for me, but the following does (change to jqueryui filename):

```
var frontendStyles = new Bundle("~/bundles/frontend.main.css")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/less", "*.less")
            .Include(
                "~/Content/ladda.css",
                "~/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css",
                "~/Content/jqueryui.1.9.2.custom.css"
            );
```

So, changing the filename from `"~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css"` to `"~/Content/bootstrapresponsive.css"` could very well sort the issue for you.