# My less page getting an error If I bundle files?

Tags: nested, less, bundle

I realized that some css are not applied on my page if I use bundling some less and css files.

```cs
yield return new StyleBundle("~/app/son/styles")
            .Include(
            "~/angular/angular-ui-select/select.css",
                "~/less/bootstrap-slider.less",
                "~/less/less/bootstrap-switch.less",
                "~/less/employee.less");
```

When I check the applied less page it s giving an error like that:

> Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
>       (248,6): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found '{'
>       (291,5): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found 'input'
>       (298,5): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found 'input'
>       (309,5): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found '{'
>       (326,12): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found '{'

For example for first error  line is like that 
 248.line(`pre {`):

```css
.example {
    pre {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

And 298 line (`td input[type="number"]`):

```css
.large-rows {
    td input[type="number"] { 
        width: 120px;
        margin-left: 4px;
    }
}
```

As I understand my less file does not behave as less file. why I m getting these errors?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660813/bundling-less-and-css-files-together.

Comment: It does not work. also I tried remove my css file from bundle, still does not work.